# Increase div height and move other divs down dynamically when inserting more text

Tags: html, css

I'm in trouble to move down other div s under the main div with text when the texts are increased.I tried so many times with css. when the text are increased with lot of enter pressing the text div height will increased but other dives doesn't move. I'm sorry about my English. What can I do for this?

this is before inserting text
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeY8Y.png

this is after inserting text
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Ik6.png

this is my code

```
    <div style="width:795px; min-height:40px; background-color:#0099FF; position:absolute; left: 60px; top: 0px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:5px; color:#FFF;font-size:14px"></div>
<span style="width:795px; min-height:40px; background-color:#0099FF; position:absolute; left: 60px; top: 0px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:5px; color:#FFF;font-size:14px"><strong>Tomorrow can be too late..</strong></span>
<div style="width:100px; height:30px; background-color:#FBC81A; position:absolute; left: 757px; top: 40px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px;z-index:1;">
  <div style="width:50px;height:30px; position:absolute; padding-top:3px;padding-left:13px;">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_report" id="btn_report" value="" style="background-image:url(images/report.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;width:23px;height:23px;border:none;background-color:#FBC81A;cursor:pointer;" title="Report this post" />
  </div>
<div style="width:50px; height:30px; position:absolute; left: 50px; background-color:#0C0; top: 0px;text-align:center;">
<div style="margin-top:7px;color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;" title="Post reputations">102</div>

</div></div>
  <div style="width:795px; min-height:340px; background-color:#F3F8F8; position:absolute ; left: 59px; border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; top: 40px;  border-left:3px #0099FF solid;border-right:3px #0099FF solid;" >
    <p>sds</p>
    <p>d</p>
    <p>sa</p>
    <p>d</p>
    <p>sad</p>
    <p>s</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>ds</p>
    <p>ad</p>
    <p>s</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>d</p>
    <p>dsa</p>
    <p>das</p>
    <p>d</p>
    <p>sa</p>
    <p>d</p>
    <p>as</p>
    <p>das</p>
    <p>d</p>
    <p>as</p>
    <p>das</p>
    <p>d</p>
    <p>sa</p>
    <p>d</p>
  </div>
  <div style="width:800px; min-height:25px; background-color:#0099FF; position:absolute; left: 60px; border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; top: 355px;" ></div>
   <div style="width:798px; min-height:20px;  position:absolute; left: 62px; border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; top: 380px;background-image:url(shadow_9.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;"  ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` on the div with the `<p>` tags in

Comment: @Andy That won't work, as that just stops the overflow. To have it grow have a padding-bottom:1px in the div with the text, this will cause the other elements to move as the text div grows.

Comment: It is because you are using position:absolute for the bar. Instead of using position:absolute try to make a layout with display:block. You need to do the following.

Use css in a separate file lot easier to edit like that.
2. Use relative positioning for the items (use float and block display).
3. Share in Jsfiddle if you have problem after that.

Comment: in where do i need to put display:block? Do i need to remove position:absolute?

Comment: Why you need to create another div to have a border at the bottom. Simply adding `border-bottom: 25px solid #0099FF` for your text container <>div and then remove your extra div will solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the `position: absolute`, `left: 60px` and `top: 355px`. This way the container will always be on the same position on the screen. U will have to use `position: relative`, use `margin` instead of `left` and `right`. Also the div is not nested correctly.

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/2xd88/1/

It think it works the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your bottom bar `<div>`:

```
<div style="width:800px; min-height:25px; background-color:#0099FF; position:absolute; left: 60px; border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; top: 355px;" ></div>
```

inside the `<div>` where you put your text (under the `<p>` tags) and change it to:

```
<div style="width:800px; min-height:25px; background-color:#0099FF; position:relative; left: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; bottom: 0px;" ></div>
```

and it will dinamically move with your text's content `<div>`